# What is the format of the coinbase transaction?

Tags: mining-pools, coinbase-transaction

I'm trying to understand the format of the coinbase transaction. I've read that it is arbitrary and not specified. I'm wondering because I need to generate mining work and create an internal pool. As I've found out, you can change the `ntime`, `nonce` and `extranonce` fields. The last one should be suited in the coinbase parameter, right? So, can anyone help me analyze the content of the coinbase transaction and how am I supposed to build one, so all miners in my pool could have different headers for hashing? A step-by-step guide on an existing block would be much appreciated, links and other stuff too.

Answer (score 22):

A coinbase transaction follows the same format as a normal transaction, except:

- It has exactly one txin
- This txin's prevout hash is 0000...0000.
- This txin's prevout index is 0xFFFFFFFF
- The txin's prevout script is an arbitrary byte array (it doesn't have to be a valid script, though this is commonly done anyway) of 2 to 100 bytes. It has to start with a correct push of the block height (see BIP34).
- The sum of the txout's values cannot exceed the subsidy (25 BTC for now, halves every 210000 blocks) plus the fees of the non-coinbase transactions in the same block.

About the scriptSig being an arbitrary byte array, there is one caveat: the checksig operations in it are counted towards the block sigop limit (20000), so you probably don't want to accidentally trigger this. Making it a list of just push operations (including of the extranonce) avoids that.

Answer (score 7):

Look at block [#280963](https://blockchain.info/block-index/461072/0000000000000002001dfbeaf7a89087854de6aa3928bbcbbd28a60d286a85c1). Look at coinbase transaction [d1c6b8...fd08](https://blockchain.info/tx/d1c6b8140246950475735394b0ac68f9ada60d313d2b5308afbc569c84f7fd08). You can see CoinBase data:

```
038349040d00456c69676975730052d8f72ffabe6d6dd991088decd13e658bbecc0b2b4c87306f637828917838c02a5d95d0e1bdff9b0400000000000000002f73733331312f00906b570400000000e4050000
```

This is a script. Look at [wiki](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Script) for details. In coinbase transaction this script can contain any data. If you change this data, merkle root will change as well, and diffirent miners can start changing nonce/timestamp for merlke root, that you provides for them. Look at [wiki](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_specification#Merkle_Trees) for more information about merkle tree.

Coinbase transaction contains single input. This is input is not used, and it contains 32 bytes zeros as previous tx. Look at [wiki](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Transactions) for more information about what data transaction contains. I provide as example of decoding raw coinbase transaction.

```
> getrawtransaction d1c6b8140246950475735394b0ac68f9ada60d313d2b5308afbc569c84f7fd08
< 01000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ffffffff53038349040d00456c69676975730052d8f72ffabe6d6dd991088decd13e658bbecc0b2b4c87306f637828917838c02a5d95d0e1bdff9b0400000000000000002f73733331312f00906b570400000000e4050000ffffffff01bf208795000000001976a9145399c3093d31e4b0af4be1215d59b857b861ad5d88ac00000000

01000000 - version
01 - input count
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 - prev tx
ffffffff - prev out n
53 - length of coinbase script
038349040d00456c69676975730052d8f72ffabe6d6dd991088decd13e658bbecc0b2b4c87306f637828917838c02a5d95d0e1bdff9b0400000000000000002f73733331312f00906b570400000000e4050000 - coinbase script
ffffffff - sequence
01 - output count
bf20879500000000 - 2508660927, satoshi count, or 25.08660927 BTC
19 - script length
76a9145399c3093d31e4b0af4be1215d59b857b861ad5d88ac - script
00000000 - locktime
```