# What makes a valid scriptSig in coinbase?

Tags: coinbase-transaction

Per BIP 34, the scriptSig should contain the height number in little endian.

Suppose the target height is 777888, which is a0de0b in little endian.
And, the extra data I want to append is a 5-byte world "hello", which is 68656c6c6f in hex.

Concatenate (encode) the height and extra data, resulting in:
03a0de0b0568656c6c6f

Does this make a valid scriptSig in the coinbase transaction?

Do I need to add other op-codes so that the evaluation of the ScriptSig is valid?

Thank you.

Comment: Related: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/20721/5406